# props.value.slice is not a function

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, react-hooks, multiselect

Quiero hacer un select simple que muestre 3 opciones: AMC1, TERN, CAM2

Y un multiselect que muestre opciones segun la opcion del select simple seleccionado

por ejemplo:

si selecciona AMC1 se muestra en el multiselect las opciones 10, 12, 14
si selecciona TERN se muestra en el multiselect las opciones 32, 34, 36
si selecciona CAM2 se muestra en el multiselect las opciones S, M, L

este es el codigo de MySelect

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { MultiSelect } from 'primereact/multiselect';

export function MySelect() {
    // Opciones del primer select
    const escalaOptions = [
        { value: 'ACM1', label: 'ACM1' },
        { value: 'TERN', label: 'TERN' },
        { value: 'CAM2', label: 'CAM2' },
    ];

    // Opciones del segundo select para cada escala
    const [tallasOptions, setTallasOptions] = useState({
        ACM1: [
            { value: '10', label: '10' },
            { value: '12', label: '12' },
            { value: '14', label: '14' },
        ],
        TERN: [
            { value: '32', label: '32' },
            { value: '34', label: '34' },
            { value: '36', label: '36' },
        ],
        CAM2: [
            { value: 'S', label: 'S' },
            { value: 'M', label: 'M' },
            { value: 'L', label: 'L' },
        ],
    });

    // Estado para controlar la opción seleccionada en el primer select
    const [selectedEscala, setSelectedEscala] = useState('');
    
    const [selectedTallas, setSelectedTallas] = useState([]);

    const handleTallasChange = (selectedTallas) => {
        setSelectedTallas(selectedTallas);
    };
    


    return (
        <div>
            <label>Escala:</label>
            <select
                value={selectedEscala}
                onChange={(e) => setSelectedEscala(e.target.value)}
            >
                <option value="">Seleccione una opción</option>
                {escalaOptions.map((option) => (
                    <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
                        {option.label}
                    </option>
                ))}
            </select>

            <label>Tallas:</label>
            <MultiSelect
                value={selectedTallas}
                options={tallasOptions[selectedEscala]}
                onChange={handleTallasChange}
                optionLabel="label"
                display="chip"
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

y este es el formulario

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import "primereact/resources/primereact.css";
import "primereact/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css";



import { MySelect } from './EscalaSelect'


export function MyForm() {



    const [selectedEscala, setSelectedEscala] = useState('');
    const [selectedTallas, setSelectedTallas] = useState([]);


    const handleTallasChange = (selectedTallas) => {
        setSelectedTallas(selectedTallas);
        console.log(setSelectedTallas);
    };


    return (
        <>
            <form style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
            

                <MySelect selectedEscala={selectedEscala} setSelectedEscala={setSelectedEscala} selectedTallas={selectedTallas} handleTallasChange={handleTallasChange} />


                
            </form>
        </>
    );
}
```

pero cuando trato de seleccionar las opciones del multiselect me aparece un error y la pagina se pone en blanco.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El metodo onChange del MultiSelect no es correcto.

Documentación: https://primereact.org/multiselect/

La propiedad **onChange** devuelve el evento del select y no el valor directamente.

Debería de ser

```
        <MultiSelect
            value={selectedTallas}
            options={tallasOptions[selectedEscala]}
            onChange={(e) => handleTallasChange(e.value)}
            optionLabel="label"
            display="chip"
        />
```